# Can't insert data in a table using entity framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I'm working with the Entity Framework and I'm having a problem:

When I try to insert some data in a table it tells me that it's violating integrity of reference but the other table is normally populated and has the value i'm trying to insert.

```
Pedido pedido = new Pedido();
pedido.Data = DateTime.Now;

db.AddToPedido(pedido);
db.SaveChanges();

EntityKey chave = db.CreateEntityKey("Pedido", pedido);
Itens_Pedido item = new Itens_Pedido();

item.Pedido_Id = Convert.ToInt32(chave.EntityKeyValues.First().Value);
item.Carta_Id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString());                    
item.Quantidade = 1;
item.Foil = "N";

db.AddToItens_Pedido(item);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: @unknown: Does that put the question title correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do your foriegn keys more like:

`item.PedidoReference.EntityKey = new System.Data.EntityKey("[EntityNamespace].Pedido", "Pedido_Id", idValue);`

where [EntityNamespace] is the namespace your entities live in.